# During XACML Policy published issue in WSO2 API

Tags: wso2, xacml, xacml2

After creating the XACML Policy trying to publish it to PDP, but getting error

> [2014-07-10 06:30:15,910] ERROR - ApplicationDispatcher
>   Servlet.service() for servlet bridgeservlet threw exception
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.stub.EntitlementPolicyAdminServiceStub.publishPolicies([Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;ZI)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.ui.client.EntitlementPolicyAdminServiceClient.publish(EntitlementPolicyAdminServiceClient.java:414)
>           at org.apache.jsp.entitlement.publish_002dfinish_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.entitlement.publish_002dfinish_jsp:133)
>           at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)

Could you please suggest to resolve the above error.

Thanks,
Asit

Comment: I've not used `wso2` but I can't help thinking your question would be easier to answer if you provided your XACML Policy and the steps/command you are using to publish it. Can you publish a different policy? (Perhaps someone else's simple example policy.)

Comment: This seems more like an issue with the method signature you used. Can you share the EntitlementPolicyAdminServiceStub version you are using at the client and the WSO2 Identity Server version in use?

Answer (score 0):

I too encountered this issue and the reason was due to some conflicts of copying org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.stub jars in different versions when installing XACML via feature manager. If you are installing XACML 2.2 and XACML mediator 2.2 it should copy org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.stub 4.2.1. I could resolve it as follows,

1. Go to /repository/components and open artifacts.xml.
     Find the artifact id 'org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.stub and change the version to 4.2.1 (there may have two artifacts with different versions 4.2.0 and 4.2.1)
2. Go to  /repository/components/default/configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator and open bundles.info file.
    Find the line org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.stub,4.2.0 and remove it. (there should be a same entry with version 4.2.1)

Then try to publish to PDP

Thanks,
Nipuni

Answer (score 0):

This has been already answered by an another SO answer,  You also can check it for more details. Please find from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25846795/unable-to-publish-xacml-policy-in-wso2-application-manager-and-throwing-nosuchme).
If you are using `APIM 1.7.0` and If you install `XACML` feature 4.2.2,  you would not see such error.